# Android 9 top left arrow (back button) of WiFi Settings works incorrectly after updating patch on August 1, 2019

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

Currently, I'm facing an issue related to `WiFi Settings` in my Homescreen app after updating security patch on August 1, 2019. I'm using an implicit intent (android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK) to open WiFi Settings. Now follow the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Start WiFi Settings using by `adb shell am start -a android.net.wifi.PICK_WIFI_NETWORK`
2. Select a network to enter credential to connect.
3. Press on <-- (top left back arrow) and it is going back to WiFi settings.
4. Press on <-- (top left back arrow) and it is going back to Settings. But I was expecting to finish the settings.

**Note**: It was working on June 1, 2019 software update but doesn't work on August 1, 2019 software update.

**Environment:**

> Device: Samsung S9+, Android: 9